# rewrite url using htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite this url

```
http://localhost/vector-svn/demo.php
```

rewrite to

```
http://localhost/vector-svn/demo
```

my .htaccess file code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.$ $1.php [nc]
```

any kind help would be appreciated ?

Comment: That RewriteRule looks ok to me. Do you have mod_rewrite.c actually enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to my own question !!
This works for url rewriting !!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

**Edit**: I see your rewrite rule is exactly the same. What problem do you have?

Comment: You could try this:
`rewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mod_rewrite is not installed at all. Check apache documentation, [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Sorry, brief answer... this link might also help you out, could be a few things and as mentioned the rewrite looks fine, so try and see if any of the following work.

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-fix-mod-rewrite-500-internal-server-error-on-htaccess-file-apache-t718.html