# How to get to php pages without using .php in URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have a static website with files like index.php, blog.php, contact.php etc

How can I get my website addresses to work so that www.site.com/blog takes you to blog.php?

I think htaccess could do this for me, but am a php noob!

The only alternative I currently use is to create individual folders called 'blog, contact etc' which contains another index.php file inside it

thanks

Comment: Have you at least read some htaccess tutorial? If yes, what did you not understand more precisely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rewrite url using htaccess file ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853968/rewrite-url-using-htaccess-file)

Comment: I don't understand the vanity around URL's, personally... Using folders is a good practice to organize code.

Comment: Well, that guys thinks php pages are "static" web pages ... that says enogh.

Comment: @marvinlabs - took a look, couldn't find what i was looking for. @fosco - I want people to be able to enter www.mydomain.com/support rather than www.mydomain.com/support.php - that was the only reason for this one @Angel O'Sphere the website is static with no backend database, php pages can of course be static if you don't add dynamic content to them!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use mod_rewrite to rewrite all urls. The following will rewrite all non-existing files and folders to requested filename .php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Visiting `/blog` and it's not an existing directory will cause this rule to rewrite it as `/blog.php`.

Comment: @Konerak Well, he did mention .htaccess so i think it's fair to assume he is using Apache.

Comment: Just to make it clear: Thats the content of the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a read on mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

> I have a static website with files like index.php, blog.php, contact.php etc

If you are generating your documents with PHP, then the site is dynamic, not static.

> How can I get my website addresses to work so that www.site.com/blog takes you to blog.php?

Assuming you are using Apache, turn on [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: Just if the extension is php does not make it a dynamic page. You can have a static page named index.php. :)

Comment: Yeah but from the context of his question one would assume it is not a static page, but now as I think about your comment, that guy perhaps has indeed pure html in his php and the server configured to return content type text/html, lol ...

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file on your server add

```
Options +MultiViews
```