# How to make adresses in my site like "sitename.domen/home", "sitename.domen/about"? Not home.php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get to php pages without using .php in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267671/how-to-get-to-php-pages-without-using-php-in-url)

Usual it looks like home.php and about.php. I need make folders "home", "about", etc. and put into files index.php?

My english is not very good, I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

.htaccess

```
##Starts Rewrite
RewriteEngine On
##The condition of the Rule is not a directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
## (^start, then match 0 or more char except . $end) [$1 point match to match.php] [L] last rule  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```